# AgGrid "serverSide" rowModel doesn't recognize custom overlay components (loading and noRows)

Tags: overlay, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

The problem is that I can not make ag-grid-react to show custom components for loadingOverlay and noRowsOverlay automatically (meaning managed by the grid itself). I've done all like described in the docs.

These are my options:

```
frameworkComponents={{
    customOverlayLoading: CustomOverlayLoading,
    customOverlayNoRows: CustomOverlayNoRows,
}}
loadingOverlayComponent="customOverlayLoading"
noRowsOverlayComponent="customOverlayNoRows"
```

Interesting thing is that it works for "clientSide" row model, e.g. when using prop `rowData={undefined}` - loading or `rowData={[]}` - noRows.

But when I replace rowData with `rowModelType="serverSide"` the grid then does not recognize new components for overlay.

There is no mention in the docs that this thing only works with clientSide row model. So I expect it should work. The way I can make it work is through the grid API. But I expect from that feature it should handle loading and noRows automatically for each of row models. The problem with the API usage is that there is no flag that points whether it is loading or not

there is the stackblitz reproduction. To check serverSide rowModel enterprise version needed
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-ro-model?embed=1&file=index.js

Comment: could you reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz? Go through how to create [mcve]

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-ro-model?embed=1&file=index.js)

Answer (score 2):

When you're using `rowModelType='serverSide'`, you need to call `overlays` yourself inside `getRows()` where you're implementing `datasource`.

```
gridApi.showNoRowsOverlay(); // show NoRowsOverlay
params.successCallback([], 0); // Pass empty array, Zero for lastRow
```

It will work. :)

Comment: Check if you get any rows back, if yes, hideOverlay and pass data and lastRow respectively.